# What happens when a high priority process arrives during a context switch between low and normal priority processes?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler

I'm Working on a scheduler simulator that will allow me evaluate alot of different scheduling algorithms in alot of different configurations.

But I'm unsure of what to do in the case where a high priority process arrives while a context switch is happening between a low and normal priority  process.

I imagine it probably varies between scheduling algorithms I just want to know the usual solution for this situation so I can make my simulation more realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Arrival* in most kernels is triggered by an interrupt or a system call.  The interrupt handler may cause some process to become ready to run, which may cause the kernel to preempt the current one.

Typically, at the point where the kernel has committed to switching to a new context, it disables interrupts until that new context is executing.
Thus the *arrival* of your higher priority process will be deferred until then.   This is one source of scheduling latency; there are typically others, and your simulation should take that into account.